Getting 'we cannot identify ourselves with either end of this connection' on IPSec connection with a gateway
I'm trying to set up a VPN connection using IPSec between a VPS and a remote network.
The exact setup worked before but this server, for some reason which I guess might be having cPanel installed, has a peer gateway attached to eth0 device.
My IPSec config is like:
$ cat /etc/ipsec.d/myconn.conf
config setup
    protostack=netkey

conn myconn
    right=RR.RR.RR.RR
    left=LL.LL.LL.LL
    rightsubnet=146.RR.RR.RR/24
    leftsubnet=172.LL.LL.LL/32
    authby=secret
    ike=aes256-sha2_256;modp2048
    phase2=esp
    phase2alg=aes256-sha2_256;modp2048
    salifetime=28800s
    ipsec-max-bytes=4608000KiB
    dpdaction=restart
    dpddelay=300
    dpdtimeout=1800
    auto=add

$ cat /etc/ipsec.d/myconn.secrets
LL.LL.LL.LL RR.RR.RR.RR : PSK "my pre shared key"

And my network configuration is like (note the peer config on eth0, which I don't know where does it come from):
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ... brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0
    inet LL.LL.LL.LL peer 169.254.0.1/32 brd LL.LL.LL.LL scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet LL.LL.LL.LL/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ..../64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ip_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0

$ ip route
default via 169.254.0.1 dev eth0
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1002
169.254.0.1 dev eth0 scope link

Connection seems to be loaded successfully but I see (the right?) IP is unrouted:
$ ipsec status
...
000 "myconn": 172.LL.LL.LL/32===LL.LL.LL.LL...RR.RR.RR.RR===146.RR.RR.RR/24; unrouted; eroute owner: #0
000 "myconn":     unoriented; my_ip=unset; their_ip=unset; my_updown=ipsec _updown;
...
000 Total IPsec connections: loaded 1, active 0

So when I try to bring up the connection I get following error:
$ ipsec auto --up myconn
022 "myconn": we cannot identify ourselves with either end of this connection.  LL.LL.LL.LL or RR.RR.RR.RR are not usable
036 "myconn": failed to initiate connection

both left and right IP's are public IP's and I can ping both.
I tried defining leftnexthop both statically to 169.254.0.1 and %defaultroute but none of them helped.
I have following nat rules as well but it would be needed for the next steps contacting the server I guess, anyway it's:
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    60 SNAT       all  --  *      *       LL.LL.LL.LL          146.RR.RR.RR/24     to:172.LL.LL.LL

Another suspect thing is on the VPS where this config is working I see the correct interface is assigned to connection on IPSec status output:
000 "myconn-dev":   conn_prio: 32,24; interface: eth0; metric: 0; mtu: unset; sa_prio:auto; sa_tfc:none;

while on this VPS with gateway I see following:
000 "myconn":   conn_prio: 32,24; interface: ; metric: 0; mtu: unset; sa_prio:auto; sa_tfc:none;

Any idea how should I configure IPSec in this case? I'd rather not to change the network configuration as I'm not fully aware of things going on this server and I don't want to randomly apply changes.

Is that openswan or libreswan? Point-to-point configuration on Ethernet is legitimate but rare, so I wouldn't be surprised if some older software didn't recognize it. (As your local address ends up being in a different field when interface addresses are queried – I suspect it might be thinking 169.254.0.1 is your local address.)

I suspect that might be the issue based on rfc3927. It's libreswan anyway.

It has nothing to do with rfc 3927.
